# Dropwizard logger filter is not working

Tags: logging, dropwizard

I have the following dropwizard logging configuration.

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.company.test.api: WARN
    com.company.app: INFO
  appenders:
  - type: file
    threshold: INFO
    timeZone: IST
    logFormat: "%highlight(%-5level) [%date] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n"
    currentLogFilename: ./logs/test.log
    archive: true
    archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/test-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log
    archivedFileCount: 50
  - type: console
    threshold: INFO
    timeZone: IST
    logFormat: "%highlight(%-5level) [%date] [%thread] [%cyan(%logger{0})]: %message%n"
```

I want to display only log level with `WARN` and above from `com.company.test.api` package. But this is not working. All the logs including `INFO` level are coming from the package. How to fix this?

Comment: I believe `loggers` settings work only on class level, not package level. I'm not 100% sure on that, so I'm just going to leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the threshold you have set in the appenders.

the following works for me:

```
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:

    # Sets the level for  package 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
    com.example.app: DEBUG
    # Sets the level for 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel' to ERROR.
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel: ERROR

  appenders:
    - type: console
      threshold: ALL
```